# Get the probable right location from multiple points

Tags: postgis, postgresql, clustering, spatial-cluster

I have a location collection tool which send me location data of our survey. Surveyors send multiple data of a single item. Such as they send numarous data for a school like the following image. From the image we can clearly identify few locations those are actually not collected properly or inaccurate location came due to GPS accuracy. Here I have marked red circle which location need to be excluded and the green circle indicates this is the probable location. IF we create a centroid based on all points then it will not indicates the probable correct location due to few highly inaccurate data. I wonder, if any method or tool can exclude the wrong location and create a cluster based on densed location points to create a centroid then the centroid can be established as probable right location of the surveyed item. I have millions of item those have hundreds of location each. I came to know that k-means do something like that but it does not do on a single item. I have four column in table.

1. fid
2. item_id
3. item_name
4. geom

Is there any method to create item wise clustering where every cluster have a value which indicates its containing points to get the probable right location?

[image]

Comment: try [`ST_GeometricMedian`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometricMedian.html); that function tries to compensate for outliers when computing a centroid for *MultiPoints*.

Comment: What @ThingumaBob says. You could also try running https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterKMeans.html a few times and finding points that are consistently a long way for computed centroids or get assigned to different clusters.

Comment: @ThingumaBob please add it to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ST_GeometricMedian`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometricMedian.html) should compensate for outliers in *MultiPoint* geometries, e.g. sth. like:

```
SELECT ST_GeometricMedian(ST_Collect(geom)) AS geom
FROM   <your_table>
GROUP BY
       item_id
;
```

[General info](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) on the concept, and difference to *weighting* (i.e. `ST_Centroid`).

---

As an alternative, using

`ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, <eps>, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY item_id)`

allows for cluster assignement over `item_id` and with an `<eps>` distance representing e.g. the specific GPS devices' standard margin of error; getting the centre of the highest populated cluster should be a precise approximation.